# Get set optional language parameter in angular 6 Home route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-params

I'm trying to pass a language code in the url like `localhost4200/en-us/` and get the language code inside the child component, but it's not working and when I try to navigate `localhost4200/en-us/` like this then my app start to request resources from `localhost4200/en-us/assets/img.png`. It is a simple onepage website made with angular.

## App routing module

```
{ path: '', component: LayoutComponent, loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule' }, 
{ path: ':locale', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }, // for language param
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent  },
```

## Home page routing module

```
{ path: '', component: Index1Component },
//{ path: ':locale', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }, // tried here also
```

## Get router param in Index1Component

```
this._route.params.subscribe(
    (param: any) => {
         let language = param['locale'];
         console.log(language); //it always returns `undefined`
     });
```

if I navigate to `localhost4200/en-us/` app doesn't work as expected and it starts to request resources from `localhost4200/en-us/assets`

I'm still learning Angular routing, what I'm doing wrong here? Is there any way to set this dynamic language parameter and I want it as optional `localhost4200/` and `localhost4200/en-us`.